# Could any native Italian speakers give me pronunciation advice please?

Tags: pronunciation

Can any native Italians please give me feedback on my pronunciation please?

http://vocaroo.com/i/s0Ky9i1XlQNT

Of course, I'm not looking for near native pronunciation, just 1) to be understood, and hopefully 2) not so bad that people will try switching to English, or maybe even 3) a foreign accent that, whilst not necessarily pleasing, but at least not repulsively strong/irritating to native listeners. Are there any particular sounds that I should focus on? Are there any that I'm getting (broadly) right, so I can concentrate on other sounds? Overall, how is the intonation and linking of individual sounds? Any other advice?

Comment: I think that the pronunciation is very good. It is not perfect by any means (in particular in my opinion you seem to struggle with the length of the vowels) but it's perfectly understandable and not at all irritating. I'll leave to someone more expert than me a more detailed feedback (again, I'll suggest concentrating on the vowels) but for now congratulations!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So are the vowel lengths overall too short or too long (or even just inconsistent)?

Comment: Your pronunciation sounds very good to me, perfectly understandable and not at all irritating.
Moreover, I can't guess exactly your mother tongue.
If I had to write down what you say, as in a dictation, not knowing the meaning of the words, I might make some mistakes.
For instance I could write "del'altro" instead of "dell'altro", "viagiattoure" instead of "viaggiatore", "alora" instead of "allora" and  "ricnoscere" instead of "riconoscere".

Comment: *Moreover, I can't guess exactly your mother tongue.* Same here. Let's start a guessing game -- I'll start: Dutch. :)

Comment: You have a good pronunciation; you tend to shorten double consonants (you pronounce *dell'altro* like *delaltro* and say *viagiatore* for *viaggiatore*; try for *del-l-l-altro* :-) ), which is quite common for foreigners. I'd guess Denmark, myself.

Comment: I completely agree with @Casamich.

Comment: Most of the comments above should be posted as answers.